# How to find the size of buffer/cache used in file system of Linux?

Tags: linux

```
root@ubuntu:~# free -wh

        total  used  free   shared  buffers  cache available
Mem:    2.0G   51M   1.7G   3.2M    20M      190M    1.8G

Swap:   2.0G    0B   2.0G
```

190 is the size of cache used, but I want to know the total size of cache in this system.

Comment: The maximum size of cache is 1.8G.

Comment: AFAIK, linux cache does not have a fixed size. It grows and shrinks with the available RAM and the memory pressure.

Comment: I mean the size of buffer used in fs. When write a file, data is not directly into disk , but into the buffer cache.

Answer (score 2):

The limit is however much available RAM memory there is, it's **not** like a file system where you have a predefined fixed maximum.

Your cache can currently be up to: total RAM (2G) minus `used` (51M) minus `shared` (3.2M) minus `buffers` (20M) ≈ 1925 MB. This limit changes as you use more (or less) RAM for applications, and the kernel will clear out (remove) parts of the cache if an application needs the space and there is not enough truly `free` space. This `cache` space can be considered 'free RAM' for applications because it's fully available to them, but it's technically in use as cache to speed up disk operations.

Try doing some large file operations, you'll see the `cache` amount snuggles up to the memory limit and your `free` amount will go down to a few megabytes.